# Check if a React component is wrapped by forwardRef

Tags: reactjs

Is there a built-in way to know if a component is already wrapped with `React.forwardRef`?

```
test(React.forwardRef(() => null))

function test(c) {
  const isForwardRef = ???
  if (!isForwardRef) {
    c = React.forwardRef(c)
  }
  // ...
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Use the `isForwardRef` function from [`react-is`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-is).

```
import {isForwardRef} from 'react-is'

isForwardRef(c)
```

https://github.com/facebook/react/blob/d48dbb824985166ecb7b2959db03090a8593dce0/packages/react-is/src/ReactIs.js#L119-L121